# How to center Google Maps to the current lat and long of the user?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to create a Store Locator with Google Maps.
I would like to center the map dynamically on the lat and long of the user.

Could someone help me in the right direction?
I already read the Google Developer Guide.
I can get the variables with help from W3Schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

But I can't get the vars in the const map:

```
function initMap() {
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude; 
    console.log(latitude);
    console.log(longitude);        
}
getLocation();
// Create the map.
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map')[0], {
zoom: 7,
center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
styles: mapStyle
});
```

Browser gives an Uncaught ReferenceError: latitude is not define`

Can someone help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Function below finds the location of the user, set a infowindow and center the map to that location. try to implement it to your app.

```
    var map, infoWindow;
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 6
      });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Try HTML5 geolocation.
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };

          infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
          infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
          infoWindow.open(map);
          map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      }
    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
    }
```

and you can find the details [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation).